# Cannot connect to the AGListener name when in SSMS on the passive node

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

We have a two node cluster built on Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012. This is a multi subnet configuration. I have tested the failover of the windows cluster and the availability group. Everything works as expected. In testing the connectivity to listener I open SSMS and can connect to the instance using the Listener name but only from the primary node. I cannot open the instance when logged into the secondary node using the listener name. I can ping the listener IP from the secondary node.

Comment: Do you need to use `MultiSubnetFailover=True`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/sqlclient-support-for-high-availability-disaster-recovery

Comment: What error do you receive? What happens after you failover, is it the same behaviour in reverse? Any firewalls between the SQL Servers? If you can ping then there is a route but maybe your SQL or Listener port is being blocked? Also, as @SqlWorldWide mentioned, you might need to use `MultiSubnetFailover=True` when connecting.